# Change Layout background on press and revert back to original

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the background color of a layout on button press and but change back to the original drawable on release.

The following code changes the background resource onclick button which changes the background but on release it stays with the new drawable resource:

```
btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIcon1);
btnOne.setOnClickListener(oneClick);
btnOne.setOnTouchListener(oneC);

    View.OnClickListener oneClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editor.putString("AndroidInfo", "1");
            editor.commit();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VersionDetail.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
        }
    };

    View.OnTouchListener oneC = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                rlOne.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dateborderclick);
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                rlOne.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dateborder);
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

dateborder xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#CCE5E5E5" />
</shape>
```

dateborderclick xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#CCD1FFFE" />
</shape>
```

dateborder is the default background. When the user interacts with the button I want the dateborder to be dateborderclick on press and back to dateborder on release. Based on the code above it should work but now the pressing works but the click doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making harder on yourself than it needs to be.  Android has a [State List Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) that takes care of this for you.  Here's what one looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize="true"
    android:dither="true"
    android:variablePadding="false">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_on" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Basically you define items that are in various states and give them a drawable.  The last one if your default state.  If you follow the link above you will see all of the different flags you can set to tune it to be exactly what you want.  Once you define this drawable just set it as the background of your button.

Comment: /i went a different route. Thanks :)